# Columns to Rows with a condition in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with columns in the format :

```
EmpNumber,PreferredPhoneType,MobilePhone,WorkPhone,HomePhone
10041,Work Phone,,342423,
```

I am trying to use :

```
select empnumber,    
DECODE(PreferredPhoneType,'Work Phone', 'W',
                    'Mobile', 'M',
                   'Home','H') result,
      MobilePhone,WorkPhone,HomePhone from xx_phone;
```

But this is retrieving all the values irrespective of the column type. I want the result to be such that if phone type is 'W' a third column should be resulted with Work phone number.

- If phone type 'M' it should come as Mobile phone number and
- If phone type 'H', it should come as Home phone number.

Something like :

```
 EmpNumber,PhoneType,Number
    1000       M         336363
    2828       W          88373
    3838       H         837373
```

Is there a function to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical application of the CASE expression.

I created some input data, showing different possible situations. I also created a small table showing which one-letter code is used for each description. If you already have these tables, you don't need the "WITH clause" at the top, just start from `select id.empnumber....`

```
with input_data (empnumber, preferredphonetype, mobilephone, workphone, homephone) as (
        select       10041, 'Work Phone'      , null       , '342423' , null      from dual union all
        select       10043, 'Mobile Phone'    , '332211'   , '443341' , '288300'  from dual union all
        select       10034, null              , '330403'   , '588923' , '455433'  from dual union all
        select       10046, 'Home Phone'      , '433223'   , '048423' , null      from dual
     ),
     phone_types (phonetype, description) as (
        select          'M', 'Mobile Phone' from dual union all
        select          'W', 'Work Phone'   from dual union all
        select          'H', 'Home Phone'   from dual
     )
select id.empnumber, pt.phonetype,
       case id.preferredphonetype
           when 'Mobile Phone' then mobilephone
           when 'Work Phone'   then workphone 
           when 'Home Phone'   then homephone
           end   as phonenumber
from input_data id left outer join phone_types pt 
                   on id.preferredphonetype = pt.description;

 EMPNUMBER PHONETYPE PHONENUMBER
---------- --------- -----------
     10043 M         332211
     10041 W         342423
     10046 H
     10034
```

Notice how 10046 has "Home Phone" shown as preferred, but she doesn't have a home phone number in the table; and 10034 has all three phone numbers, but no preferred phone type, so BOTH values are left blank (null) for this employee.